# How to access contact information from a React.js website

Tags: web-apps, javascript, web-development, web-browser, react

I'd like to add a contact in a user's mobile contacts app from a web browser using a React.js web application. Ideally, I'd like this to work for both android and iOS devices. How could I do this?

Comment: imho a website cant simply access to mobile data (eg. contacts) for security reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Support is patchy I think: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Contact_Picker_API